# Easing page scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is there anyway to ease my page scroll? I'm doing a horizontal page scrolling. Its working, as you can see below, but I want to make a ease scroll.

Already tried to scroll it whit css3 transitions on jQuery (via Transit) and didnt work because it triggers too many times.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

```
     $('#holder')
        .bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 20);      
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use animate function. A simple example I have done is here

http://jsfiddle.net/bd6pf/2/

Scroll to the right and and try to scroll on element

Comment: @Lucas yes this will work, jsfiddle just isnt a big fan of mousewheel events

Comment: oh sorry! try again! Wrong URL I guess! :)

Comment: No worries. I am glad it helped. Sorry for the wrong revision URL :)

Answer (score -1):

I have been over this and its best to just use jQuery to do this or at least javascript, I know its cool to use CSS3 and I try to use it as often as possible but in this case I would stick with the javascript.

Here is a great one that I have used:
http://pagescroller.com/